# get list of IDs from DB and Pass them to Retrofit interface

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android

I am trying to pass set of IDs to retrofit interface

```
 @GET("story")
 Observable<StoryCollectionEntity> storyCollection(
          @Query("feed_ids") Set<Long> feedIds // this is the ids i want to pass,
          @Query("page") int page);
```

Those IDs retrieved from DB and should be passed to api in comma separated  i.e. like: 1,2,4,.. or just one value like 1 or 2

to retrieve ids from DB i wrote the following code:

```
//retrieve ids from DB
public Observable<Set<Long>> getFeedIdsFromDB() {
  return Observable.create(subscriber -> {
  Set<Integer> subscribedFeedIds = new HashSet<>();
     for (FeedEntity feed : FeedEntity.listAll(FeedEntity.class)){
        if (feed.isSubscribed()){
           subscribedFeedIds.add(feed.getFeedId());
        }
       }});
      }
```

in rest repository, call for response then do mapping:

```
public Observable<StoryList> stories(int page) {
  return newsDataStore.storyEntityList(page)
   .map(StoryList -> this.mNewsEntityDataMapper.transform(StoryList));
 }
```

storyEntityList :

```
 @Override
 public Observable<StoryCollectionEntity> storyEntityList(final int page)   {
 return Observable.create(subscriber -> {
     this.mNewsCache.getFeedIdsFromDB()
    .flatMap(id ->this.restApi.storyCollection(id, page));
 });
```

unfortunately this code is not working for me. i am not sure what is the exact problem as i see nothing happens after `getFeedIdsFromDB()` is called. in other word, no mapping is taken place in the last Observable.

Comment: Check this out.  https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/611

Comment: i found that not fit my case.